# PHP attach audio file in email

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm using the following SMTP mail code to send audio attachment:

```
<?php

session_start();

$title = $_POST['title'];
$first_name = $_POST['name'];
$last_name = $_POST['lastname'];
$email_from = $_POST['email'];
$scaptcha = strtolower($_POST['scaptcha']);
if ($scaptcha != $_SESSION['captcha']) {
    echo 'You have entered wrong captcha';
    exit(0);
}

require('./class.phpmailer.php');

function clean_string($string) {
    $bad = array("content-type", "bcc:", "to:", "cc:", "href");
    return str_replace($bad, "", $string);
}

$email_message = "";
$email_message .= "Title: "      . clean_string($title)      . "\n";
$email_message .= "First Name: " . clean_string($first_name) . "\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: "  . clean_string($last_name)  . "\n";
$email_message .= "Email: "      . clean_string($email_from) . "\n";

$allowedExts = array("mp3","wav","dss");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mpeg")) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
        echo "<script>alert('Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "')</script>";
    } else {
        $d = 'Audio/Uploads/';
        $de = $d . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $de);
        $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $filePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    }
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('Invalid file')</script>";
}

$headers = 'From: ' . $email_from . "\r\n" .
           'Reply-To: ' . $email_from . "\r\n" .
           'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "saro17.ams@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "*****";
$mail->SetFrom($email_from, $first_name . ' ' . $last_name);
//$mail->AddReplyTo('replyto@example.com','First Last');
$mail->AddAddress('saro17.ams@gmail.com', 'Saravana');
$mail->Subject = 'New audio file received';
$mail->MsgHTML($email_message);
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name']);

if (!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "<script>alert('Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo . "')</script>";
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('Your request has been submitted. We will contact you soon.')</script>";
    Header('Location: contact.php');
}

?>
```

Please help me to fix this. I have been trying this for more than a week. Still I didn't get it. I have tried the PHP mailer also. That also not working.

**UPDATE:** I'm getting the following error:

> Mailer Error: The following From address failed: saro17.ams@gmail.com : Called MAIL FROM without being connected,

Comment: The problem is on this line: `$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name']);`

Comment: Do you get any errors? And does the email get send at all?

Comment: I'm getting the following error --- Mailer Error: The following From address failed: saro17.ams@gmail.com : Called MAIL FROM without being connected,,

Comment: Well..It will be a really good practice to use `PHPMailer` Here is the link : https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: It is being used -  $mail = new PHPMailer();

Comment: can you post the full error in your question

Comment: I'm getting the following error --- Mailer Error: The following From address failed: saro17.ams@gmail.com : Called MAIL FROM without being connected,, (saro17.ams@gmail.com is from address)

Answer (score 0):

send the audio file link in message instead of inline attachment.

$mail->AddAttachment method use for inline attachment.

due to the file encryption and file size , maximum server not allow to send inline attachment of audio, video or zip files.

Answer (score 0):

Well..It's really very easy to attach anything while using `PHPMailer`.Here is the code :

**PHPMailer Link :** https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

You can add attachments like :

```
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
```

While here is full code :

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Comment: I tried this code.Getting this error --- Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: The following From address failed: saravana17.ams@gmail.com : MAIL FROM command failed,Authentication Required. Learn more at https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 a22sm42385348pfj.2 - gsmtp ,530,5.5.1

Comment: @saravananam : Well it seems like your code may work but you are having problem in logging in to your gmail account..!

Comment: yes.I got one email telling that sign-in attempt prevented.Could you please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: @saravananam : Update your code according to these given details..So it may work then : `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';`
`$mail->Port = 587; `  Let me know if that fixes the problem..

Comment: @saravananam : Are you saying you already tried with the 587 port and still it's not working???